# how to run a code efor 1000 times using for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe, dataset

I have this code which produces different "auc" each time I run it. I would like to run this code for 1000 times in order to calculate the mean of the 1000 stored AUC. how can I apply for loop to do what Iam looking for? it would be appreciated if you guys do it for me and paste the new code. as I have been trying to solve since 4 days now.

```
#iris is a built-in dataset
main_df<- iris
# extract data for "setosa"
setosa <-main_df[main_df$Species=="setosa" ,]
# extract data for "virginica"
virginica<-main_df[main_df$Species=="virginica" ,]
#merge "setosa" and "virginica" as new dataset
df<- rbind(setosa,virginica)

Cross.AUC<-rep(0,1000) # create a vector of zeros, here will be stored the auc values from each of 1000 runs
for (i in seq(1:1000)) {
#---------------devide data into two datasets 70:30 train:test ----
#---------------train dataset
#select randomly 70% of setosa, generates a 35-by-5 matrix
setosa_70<-setosa[sample(nrow(setosa),round(0.7*dim(setosa)[1])),]
#select randomly 70% of virginica, generates a 35-by-5 matrix
virginica_70<-virginica[sample(nrow(virginica),round(0.7*dim(virginica)[1])),]
#merge setosa and virginica
train<-rbind(setosa_70,virginica_70)
#convert "setosa" to "0" and "virginica" to 1""
train$Species<-ifelse(train$Species=="setosa",0,1)
#select 1st, 2nd and 5th columns
train <-subset(train,select = c(1,2,5))
#--------------test dataset
#select randomly 30% of setosa, generates a 15-by-5 matrix
setosa_30<-setosa[sample(nrow(setosa),round(0.3*dim(setosa)[1])),]
#select randomly 30% of virginica, generates a 15-by-5 matrix
virginica_30<-virginica[sample(nrow(virginica),round(0.3*dim(virginica)[1])),]
#merge setosa and virginica
test<-rbind(setosa_30,virginica_30)
#convert "setosa" to "0" and "virginica" to 1""
test$Species<-ifelse(test$Species=="setosa",0,1)
#select 1st, 2nd and 5th columns
test <-subset(test,select = c(1,2,5))
#merge "train" and "test"
train_test<-rbind(train,test)
#--Model_1--
model <-glm(Species~., family = binomial(link = "logit"),data = train_test)
# install.packages("ROCR")
library(ROCR)
p <- predict(model, newdata=test, type="response")
pr <- prediction(p, test$Species)
auc <- performance(pr, measure = "auc")
auc <- auc@y.values[[1]]
AUC[i]<-auc
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `AUC` with `Cross.AUC`. You don't have any object called `AUC` defined in the scope which you can access in the `for` loop.

```
#iris is a built-in dataset
main_df<- iris
# extract data for "setosa"
setosa <-main_df[main_df$Species=="setosa" ,]
# extract data for "virginica"
virginica<-main_df[main_df$Species=="virginica" ,]
#merge "setosa" and "virginica" as new dataset
df<- rbind(setosa,virginica)

Cross.AUC<-rep(0,1000) # create a vector of zeros, here will be stored the auc values from each of 1000 runs
for (i in seq(1:1000)) {
  #---------------devide data into two datasets 70:30 train:test ----
  #---------------train dataset
  #select randomly 70% of setosa, generates a 35-by-5 matrix
  setosa_70<-setosa[sample(nrow(setosa),round(0.7*dim(setosa)[1])),]
  #select randomly 70% of virginica, generates a 35-by-5 matrix
  virginica_70<-virginica[sample(nrow(virginica),round(0.7*dim(virginica)[1])),]
  #merge setosa and virginica
  train<-rbind(setosa_70,virginica_70)
  #convert "setosa" to "0" and "virginica" to 1""
  train$Species<-ifelse(train$Species=="setosa",0,1)
  #select 1st, 2nd and 5th columns
  train <-subset(train,select = c(1,2,5))
  #--------------test dataset
  #select randomly 30% of setosa, generates a 15-by-5 matrix
  setosa_30<-setosa[sample(nrow(setosa),round(0.3*dim(setosa)[1])),]
  #select randomly 30% of virginica, generates a 15-by-5 matrix
  virginica_30<-virginica[sample(nrow(virginica),round(0.3*dim(virginica)[1])),]
  #merge setosa and virginica
  test<-rbind(setosa_30,virginica_30)
  #convert "setosa" to "0" and "virginica" to 1""
  test$Species<-ifelse(test$Species=="setosa",0,1)
  #select 1st, 2nd and 5th columns
  test <-subset(test,select = c(1,2,5))
  #merge "train" and "test"
  train_test<-rbind(train,test)
  #--Model_1--
  model <-glm(Species~., family = binomial(link = "logit"),data = train_test)
  # install.packages("ROCR")
  library(ROCR)
  p <- predict(model, newdata=test, type="response")
  pr <- prediction(p, test$Species)
  auc <- performance(pr, measure = "auc")
  auc <- auc@y.values[[1]]
  Cross.AUC[i]<-auc
}

cat('Mean AUC:', mean(Cross.AUC), '\n')
```